# How to parse json file in Octave?

Tags: json, octave

As in the title, is there a built-in way of parsing/decoding a `.json` file in Octave?

I have gone through the Octave documentation, and different tools, but the only thing I have found is this tool:
https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab

**EDIT:**
The purpose is to be able to use the same json config file for two different environments: python and octave. So the would be:
1. Define the config;
2. Run octave script, reading the config from `config.json`;
3. Run python script, reading the config from `config.json`;

I am using at the moment the jsonlab toolset for octave, and since the json is fairly simple, it is working really good. Question is coming from pure curiosity of why octave does not implement a json serialization library by default.

So, since the json is simple, solution for me is to use https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab. From the comments below, seems that that is not perfect to be used with more complex jsons.

Comment: Is JSONlab not sufficient for your needs? Why do you need a built-in?

Comment: The `io` package contains an `object2json` function to _encode_ an octave object to json. The _reverse_ function doesn't exist, but in a sense, it doesn't make immediate sense to have one anyway, because for a json file to be successfully decoded to octave variables it would have to be a very specific json format compatible with octave binary objects anyway, so you might as well save in octave binary format in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth telling us what your underlying 'problem' is that you're trying to solve with json. Often enough such questions end up being a case of [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/), and there might be a much simpler solution for your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used JSONlab for many projects for a long time but because it was very slow and some points didn't fulfilled my expectation I wrote a octave wrapper around rapidjson: https://github.com/Andy1978/octave-rapidjson

README.md shows some examples. One example to get a reply from a server as JSON, then convert it to a struct:

```
octave:1> x = load_json (urlread ("http://headers.jsontest.com/"))
x =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    X-Cloud-Trace-Context = 61910c1954c45fe021d35aeeb5477c20/2702800337619378204
    Host = headers.jsontest.com
    Accept = */*

octave:2> x.Host
ans = headers.jsontest.com
```

The other way:

```
octave:11> a.x = 5; a.y = {1,2,"foobar"}; a.z = rand(2); save_json (a)
ans = {
    "x": 5.0,
    "y": [
        1.0,
        2.0,
        "foobar"
    ],
    "z": [
        [
            0.6835708677160701,
            0.891779233104656
        ],
        [
            0.9378550691771155,
            0.664043049215685
        ]
    ]
}
```